# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module: when running Jest-expo tests

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs, expo

The configuration for the project. Currently using jest-expo for testing in this project. The version of jest-expo in the project is 39.0.0. Version of Jest installed globally is 26.6.3

**package.json** :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest",
    "type": "module"
  },
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "jest-expo": "^39.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
  },
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  }
```

**jest.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
      './setup-tests.js',
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/lib/index.js",
      "/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/(?!(lib))",
      "/node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/.*",
      "node_modules/native-base/.*",
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*|native-base-*|native-base-shoutem-*)"
    ],
    verbose : true
  };
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['inline-dotenv'],
  };
};
```

I am trying to render a snapshot for a login page that is react-native:

The error is caused by the below import module inside **LoginScreen.js**

```
import {
    Content,
    Container,
    H2,
    Form,
    Item,
    Input,
    Button,
    Text,
    View,
} from "native-base";
```

Test case inside **LoginScreen.test.js**

```
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders LoginScreen correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<LoginScreen />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Test case is throwing the **error**

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import connectStyle, { clearThemeCache } from "./src/connectStyle";
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1258:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/native-base/src/index.js:1:1)
```

[image]

I have tried other similar answers available on Stack Overflow. But none of them applied to the current project on which I am working with.

I have added `connectStyle` to the Jest `transformIgnorePatterns` but still it is throwing that error.

Current Project :
React native mobile application developed using expo.
Using jest-expo for testing.
Configuration of the project.
[image: Current configuration of the project]

Tried uninstalling and re-installing all the npm and expo modules, that didn't help either.

Comment: And your version of Jest is......?

Comment: Currently using jest-expo for testing in this project. The version of jest-expo in the project is 39.0.0. Version of Jest installed globally is 26.6.3.

Comment: remember to put those details in the post. That is certainly a new enough version to have all the ES module support that recently landed.  Looking at the code you're getting an error flagged in: that's not even valid code, it's some kind of bundle with illegal import syntax, so in addition to asking here, you almost definitely need to ask this on the expo issue tracker, too. This could very just be a bad bug, but they're by far the better folks to ask.

Comment: Sure Mike, I will raise this on the expo forum also. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This is an issue with native-base. https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3084  https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3105

Comment: one thing you can try is to figure is to force jest to run with `--experimental-vm-modules` (see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules, point 2) but that's all I can think of to maybe make things work anyway.

Comment: Tried ```--experimental-vm-modules``` but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Then you should probably file an issue on the jest-expo issue tracker. If their project, out of the box, leads to errors, they will want to know about that, so they can figure out a way forward.

Comment: I have raised this on the expo issue tracker as mentioned by you already https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11012. There is an open issue for the same on the native-base issue page https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3105

Answer (score 2):

This is an open issue on the Native base end. Further details can be found on this ticket :

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3105